# Can't enable spell checker option in Xcode

Tags: macos, mac, xcode, spellcheck

[image: Option is greyed out]

Option is greyed out and I cannot enable spell checking in Xcode

Comment: Same issue, happened after updating Xcode to 9.0

Comment: any update on this issue? I'm still having this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: was spell checking available before? im having a hard time imagining how it would have been useful

Comment: @user3052786 Yes, it was, in Xcode 8.3 on High Sierra, the spell checker menu is not grayed out.

Comment: @jaume Ohh.. I just noticed that the cursor was in a comment in the OP. I guess it would be useful in that case. I was able to enable it by manually choosing the language in the Spelling & Grammar menu, although I can't say it restores the functionality it had before, the menu items  are un-greyed out (if that's a thing) when I do that.

Comment: @jaume But even for comments, I'd imagine using the spellchecker for standard US dictionary would be more annoying than helpful, wouldn't it try to change capitalization and insert spaces in variable names and such?

Comment: Yes it was working before `CMD+;` and was able to check spelling of camel case symbols (but it always underlined whole symbol in case of typos), I miss this feature a lot too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug. I am not sure if it has been fixed. Try make sure you’re on the latest Xcode version.

From [Stack Overflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412301/xcode-9-spell-check-greyed-out)

> I believe this is a duplicate post but I'll answer anyway.
>   This is an Xcode bug. There have been radars filed. As far as I am unaware there is no work around or fix currently.

That was posted at a similar time to when this was posted.

Answer (score -2):

> Make sure you are doing it while in a mail composition window, not in message viewer. The spellchecking option is grayed out in message viewer because you can not edit received messages.

([source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2326222))

Comment: What mail composition window?! It's about Xcode

Comment: To me it just seems like you copied the first thing that came up in google, pasted it from here  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2326222 gave no attribution and not even read it to see if it’s relevant